# Disabling F1 key: lots of problems

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, bios, acer-aspire, fn-key

I want to disable the commands associated to my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys in particular the <kbd>F1</kbd> command which activates the sleep mode. In addition <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys alone are not present in the Keyboard Shortcuts (in the settings). I tried several unsuccessful ways:

- I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200893/how-to-disable-multimedia-keys-entirely-18-04-lts) but I am not able to find the <kbd>F1</kbd> key removal.
- I tried to assign an "empty" command to <kbd>F1</kbd> via Keyboard Shortcuts I notice that the name of <kbd>F1</kbd> is "sleep". In this way <kbd>F1</kbd> is no longer associated to sleep mode but I cannot use it for other programs.
- Via bios settings. Typically the <kbd>Fn</kbd> settings should be located in the bios advanced settings. Anyway I cannot find them.
- There are [other ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818413/how-can-i-toggle-the-fn-function-key) like <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> which should remove the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys default functions. Anyway this command doesn't work with my laptop. I have also tried these commands with other <kbd>Fn</kbd>'s.

My ubuntu version is 20.10.
My laptop is an Acer Aspire 3 A315-56.

Comment: The answer will depend on your manufacturer, model, and the motherboard. It is controlled in the BIOS and you should be able to switch off the functions assigned by your manufacturer. (In many programs, the F1 key is very helpful, often the Help key.)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't have the sleep command in the _Keyboard Shortcuts_. In fact I have created a custom shortcut in order to make F1 button "frozen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the BIOS:

*Function key behaviour*  --->  *Function key*.

while the default setting is Media Key. If, for example, <kbd>F1</kbd> is associated to sleep mode, using *function key* setting, you have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> in order to have the sleep mode.

In the BIOS function key behaviour can be found inside a subsection of *advanced* like *other*.